# Can't link object file using ld - Mac OS X

Tags: c, assembly, shellcode

```
/*********
exit.asm
*/

[SECTION .text]

global _start


_start:
xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
mov al, 1
int 0x80

//****************************
```

First I used nasm -f elf exit.asm to generate the object file.

then I ran the following "ld" command on my Mac OS X 10.7, it has the these outputs and warning, I tried to run it on my 32 bit linux machine, everything went through just fine,
Could you please explain why would not the linker work on my Mac?

Thank you!

```
Alfred says: ld -o exiter exit.o
ld: warning: -arch not specified
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.7
ld: warning: ignoring file exit.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7f 0x45      0x4c 0x46 0x 1 0x 1 0x 1 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the   architecture being linked (x86_64): exit.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "start", referenced from:
    implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64
```

after I specify my arch and version, I got:

```
Alfred says: ld -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.7 -o exiter exit.o
ld: warning: ignoring file exit.o, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7f 0x45     0x4c 0x46 0x 1 0x 1 0x 1 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 0x 0 ) which is not the   architecture being linked (x86_64): exit.o
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "start", referenced from:
    implicit entry/start for main executable
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Answer (score 9):

Getting the program to link is the easy part:

- Change `_start` to `start`
- `$ nasm -f macho exit.asm`
- `$ ld -arch i386 -o exiter exit.o`

The problem is that `exit.asm` is calling the i386 Linux `exit()` system call (**EAX** = 1) and the program would *NOT* exit with a zero status as intended on OS X.

### System Calls

A *system call* is a request to the kernel. `exit()`, unlike `sqrt()`, must make a request to a software component with higher privileges in its implementation since it terminates a running program. Apps can't create or terminate processes by themselves. System calls provide a way for apps to ask the kernel to perform actions on their behalf.

Making a syscall goes something like this:

- Apps describe the operation they want to perform by placing data in CPU registers (or memory pointed to by registers), e.g.

  - The value `1` in **EAX** is the system call number of `exit`.
  - The value `0` in **EBX** (**EBX** was cleared by `xor`) is the first argument to the syscall, the exit status.
- Apps issue an instruction that causes control to transfer to the kernel, e.g.

  - `int 80` on i386
  - `sycall` on x86-64
  - `svc` in Thumb mode on ARMv7
- The kernel inspects the request and decides to perform or deny it.
- The kernel transfers control back to the app with the return value in an agreed upon location, e.g. **EAX** on i386.

Linux and OS X both provide a `void exit(int)` function for C programs but don't agree on the details on how to describe this request to the kernel. The code in `exit.asm` is at the same level as the implementation of the `_exit()` function in `libc`.

Even between different architectures running Linux the syscall numbers and calling convention differ. e.g. On x86-64 Linux, `exit(0)` is more commonly issued like this:

```
xor rdi, rdi
mov al, 60
syscall
```

You can see this by disassembling `_exit` in `/lib64/libc.so.6`.

### Can't We Just Call exit() from libc Instead?

You can. But you'd have to link the program with `libc`. It's the difference between linking `exit.asm` above with:

```
$ cc -m32 -nostdlib exit.o -o exiter
```

and

**exit-libc.asm**

```
extern exit
global main
main:
push 0
call exit
```

which has to be linked with:

```
$ cc -m32 exit-libc.o -o exit-libc
```

Try this and take a look at the file size.

Answer (score 5):

Mac OS X doesn't use ELF, so you'll want to generate a Mach-O object to link with on that system.  On my machine `nasm` appears to only support 32-bit output, so you'll need to match that architecture when linking, too.

I also had to change `_start` to `start` to get it to link.

Here's a working example with your code:

```
$ cat exit.asm 
[SECTION .text]

global start

start:
xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
mov al, 1
int 0x80
$ nasm -f macho exit.asm 
$ ld -arch i386 -macosx_version_min 10.7  -o exiter exit.o 
$ ./exiter 
$ echo $?
236
```

Note that the program probably doesn't do what you want on Mac OS X, since it doesn't do system calls the same way as Linux.

Comment: thanks, do you have any good resources covering the asm - obj files - dynamic linking - executables for Mac OSX?

Answer (score 3):

Most of the time when you receive this error:

```
ld: warning: PIE disabled. Absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) not 
allowed in code signed PIE, but used in _start from hello.o. To fix this 
warning, don't compile with -mdynamic-no-pic or link with -Wl,-no_pie
```

It is because it is looking for your "main()" function(label) to me the label "start:". It is always best to specify the your main label with "ld -e".

#### For nasm:

```
-o hello.tmp - outfile
-f macho - specify format
Linux - elf or elf64
Mac OSX - macho
```

#### For ld:

```
-arch i386 - specify architecture (32 bit assembly)
-macosx_version_min 10.6 (Mac OSX - complains about default specification)
-no_pie (Mac OSX - removes ld warning)
-e main - specify main symbol name (Mac OSX - default is start)
-o hello.o - outfile
```

#### For Shell:

```
./hello.o - execution
```

#### One-liner:

```
nasm -o hello.tmp -f macho hello.s && ld -arch i386 -macosx_version_min 10.6 -no_pie -e _main -o hello.o hello.tmp && ./hello.o
```

Let me know if this helps!

I wrote how to do it on my blog here:

http://blog.burrowsapps.com/2013/07/how-to-compile-helloworld-in-intel-x86.html

For a more verbose explanation, I explained on my Github here:

https://github.com/jaredsburrows/Assembly

Comment: Thanks, this works on my machine and your answer is understandable as well.

Comment: Hey, the execution is not working. Linking is done without any errors. I have a code for printing "Hello World" but on running your command, it doesn't print anything. Can you help?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

The standard mac gcc won't link elf objects. For people who need to stick with the elf format and develop on a mac, you need a cross compiler...

http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php?id=compiling_for_linux

Then you can proceed with something similar to this...

```
/usr/local/gcc-4.8.1-for-linux32/bin/i586-pc-linux-ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel kasm.o kc.o
```